# Requirement problem installing laravel-websockets

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to install laravel-websockets package but I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\AdoptaUnaTiaBE>composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
Using version ^1.12 for beyondcode/laravel-websockets
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for pusher/pusher-php-server 7.0.1 -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-php-server[7.0.1].
    - beyondcode/laravel-websockets 1.12.0 requires pusher/pusher-php-server ^3.0|^4.0|^5.0 -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-php-server[5.0.x-dev].
    - beyondcode/laravel-websockets 1.x-dev requires pusher/pusher-php-server ^3.0|^4.0|^5.0 -> satisfiable by pusher/pusher-php-server[5.0.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install pusher/pusher-php-server 5.0.x-dev
    - Installation request for beyondcode/laravel-websockets ^1.12 -> satisfiable by beyondcode/laravel-websockets[1.12.0, 1.x-dev].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I tried changing composer.json to

```
"pusher/pusher-php-server": "7.0.1",
```

and using

```
composer update pusher/pusher-php-server
```

It didn't work, I also trtied directly yo do:

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server 7.0.1
```

but no solution, what can I do?

This os part of my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
        "beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.12",
        "christiankuri/laravel-favorite": "^1.4",
        "fabpot/goutte": "^4.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "7.4.x-dev",
        "laravel-notification-channels/fcm": "~2.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.6",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "mailgun/mailgun-php": "^3.0",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "7.0.1",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.4"
    },
```

Comment: Seems like step 1 would be upgrade composer. "Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available."

Comment: And it says right in the error "beyondcode/laravel-websockets 1.12.0 requires pusher/pusher-php-server ^3.0|^4.0|^5.0" so why would you try forcing version 7.0.1?